# Enforcing parameter types on dependent interfaces?

Tags: java, generics

These interfaces are very simple:

```
public interface Thawed<F>
{
    F freeze();
}

public interface Frozen<T>
{
    T thaw();
}
```

This works, no problem.

But now, how would I require `F` in `Thawed` to implement `Frozen`, and `T` in `Frozen` to implement `Thawed`?

The closest I could get is:

```
public interface Thawed<F extends Frozen<? extends Thawed<F>>>

public interface Frozen<T extends Thawed<? extends Frozen<T>>>
```

But that sounds quite recursive... (also works with `Thawed<?>` and `Frozen<?>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The closest I could get is

That is the correct answer; you cannot get better than that within the Java type system.

---

Note that this does allow

```
class Cat implements Thawed<Dog> { }
class HouseCat extends Cat { }
class Dog implements Frozen<HouseCat> { }
```

You could prevent that by using two generic parameters:

```
public interface Thawed<F extends Frozen<T, F>, T extends Thawed<F, T>> { }

public interface Frozen<T extends Thawed<F, T>, F extends Frozen<T, F>> { }
```

However, I think this is too confusing to be useful.

It would also still allow

```
class Cat implements Thawed<Dog, HouseCat> { }

class HouseCat extends Cat { }

class Dog implements Frozen<HouseCat, Dog> { }
```

Comment: Yeah, well, classes using this are all `final` -- in my code, at least. Cannot guarantee this when others get to use it ;) Thanks for clearing my doubts!

Comment: @fge: On second thought, you can get better than that.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
public interface Thawed<F extends Frozen<?>> { ... }

public interface Frozen<T extends Thawed<?>> { ... }
```

I don't think you need anything deeper than that, since all you need to do is specify that `F` is some kind of `Frozen` (and similarly for `T`).

Comment: `class Cat implements Thawed<Dog>` `class Dog implements Frozen<Cow>`

Comment: @SLaks - But the definition of `Thawed` requires `Dog` to extend `Frozen<?>` (etc.) which is what OP wants. OP didn't say that the two classes needed to be inverses of one another (e.g., that the `Frozen` you get back when you freeze a `Cat` will yield a `Cat` again when thawed. It might yield dog food. :)

Comment: I thought that was implied.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for -- that the two classes are "linked" by this freeze/thaw relationship. Looks like I have to let go of some... slack (sorry :p) and go with a "good enough" solution in any case...